# Need to remove extra square brackets in the string

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, stringbuffer

```
static ArrayList<String> coordinates = new ArrayList<String>();
static String str = "";
static ArrayList scribbles = new ArrayList();

coordinates.add("String to be placed, String not to be placed");
String codChange = coordinates.toString().replaceAll(", ", "");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(codChange);
sb.insert(1,"m ");
ArrayList aListNumbers = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(sb.toString()));
System.out.println("Coordinates: " + aListNumbers.toString().replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));
                scribbles.add(aListNumbers);
str = scribbles.toString();
System.out.println("String: " + str);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Coordinates: m String to be placedString not to be placed
String: [[m String to be placedString not to be placed]]
```

I want the String: to appear with single square brackets like:

```
String: [m String to be placedString not to be placed]
```

Comment: `replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));` what you are trying to do in this? what is the original output without the above replaceAll? or the replaceAll is not at all working for the regEx string you have given

Comment: when i add an arraylist "aListNumbers" in another arraylist "scribbles" it is adding two square brackets. i don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are two different replacement required.

Use below code

```
String s = "[[m String to be placedString not to be placed]]";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[[","[").replaceAll("]]","]");
```

If you are sure about always the exact position of [[ is at the beginning and ]] is at end, just use substring as suggested in the other answer in the same SO answer thread.

Comment: The problem comes when i try to add arraylist in another arraylist in this statement: scribbles.add(aListNumbers);

Comment: meaning while printing toString method `System.out.println("String: " + str);`?

Comment: yes. my str becomes [ [String to be placedString not to be placed] ]

Comment: Since you are using java.util.ArrayList, class which is not owned by you, you cannot override toString() method of it. Only thing you can do is perform the above operation after while getting `toString` String object. i.e. like `System.out.println("String: " + str.replaceAll("[[","[").replaceAll("]]","]");`